# Can't capture keypress event when bootstrap modal is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, marionette

For some reason I can't capture a simple keydown event in a view when it is active in a bootstrap modal.

I declare my view/modal like this:

```
cardFrontView = new CardFrontView(model: @model)
app.layout.card_front.show(cardFrontView)
$('.card-front.modal').modal()
```

And in my Card View I listen for events like this:

```
events:
    'click': () ->
        console.log 'click'
    'keydown': () ->
        console.log 'keydown'
```

The click event registers, but not the keydown event. I'm currently working around it by listening for the keydown event in my AppLayout view, but this is suuuper hacky.

Does anyone know why bootstrap modals would be messing with the keydown/keypress events?

Answer (score 0):

You could try initialising your modal with no keyboard events. From the docs:

```
$('#myModal').modal({ keyboard: false })   // initialized with no keyboard
```

I am guessing there is already some in-built mechanism to handle navigation/closing which is interfering with your own events.

Answer (score 0):

Been doing some research and apparently bootstrap modals take the element out of the DOM...? There are some articles that provide some workarounds, but I've just built my own barebones marionette modal plugin. I'll publish the link here when it's ready for general use.